# removing padding from column transposition c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, padding, multidimensional-array

I have done a column transposition (see first part below) and i'm working with bytes to transposition an image (for encryption purposes) because I am using a 2D array I have had to use padding to fill the remaining contents of the array I am struggling to find a efficient way of removing the padding when reversing the process without distorting the original data - please does someone have  any suggestions or guidance or alternative you can provide?

```
            for (int i = 0; i < colsize; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < rowsize; j++)
                {

                    if (itt < data.Length)
                    {
                        matrix[i, j] = data[itt];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //padding array element with *
                    }

                    itt++;
                }
            }
```

Any help will be much appreaciated

Comment: Is the amount of data in `itt` known? Or can you make the matrix bigger, or can you store external material? Are there any out of bounds values possible in the matrix? If all of the above is a negative then a deterministic scheme may not be possible. Please indicate which of the above is true.

Comment: yes the amount of in is known, the matrix is a fixed size as it is a 2d array so in theory i cant make it bigger, and no out of bounds values in the matrix as it is a fixed size - hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to simulate what is called PKCS#7 padding within the array. This means that you store the amount of data left in the last element of the row. You can simply retrieve the value of the last element, which determines what amount of data is unused. In PKCS#7 this padding value is also repeated in the other unused bytes, but this isn't strictly required.

The problem occurs if you don't have any bytes left, you cannot determine if the value contains the amount of values that should not be used, or that it contains an actual value. Just like in PKCS#7 padding, the solution could be to add an extra row.

Obviously, storing the length or the amount of padding externally is also an option.